# Qt android compilation error

Tags: android, c++, qt

I installed Qt 5.4 on my windows 7 x64 (disk D) and created simplest Qt widget prgram.
I'm trying to run it on my physical device (Samsumg galaxy S5 mini) Google USB driver installed and Qt can see physical device but after compilation I have this error:

> The system cannot find the path specified
>   makefile:1628: recipe for target 'install_target' failed
>   mingw32-make: [install_target] Error 1 (ignored)
>
> Application binary is not in output directory: D:/Qt Samples/build-AndroidGio-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_2-Debug/android-build//libs/armeabi/libAndroidGio.so. Please run 'mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=D:/Qt Samples/build-AndroidGio-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_2-Debug/android-build/' first.
>   18:51:56: The process "D:\Qt\5.4\android_armv5\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" exited with code 7.
>   Error while building/deploying project AndroidGio (kit: Android for armeabi (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.4.2))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

how can I run "mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=D:/Qt Samples/build-AndroidGio-Android_for_armeabi_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_4_2-Debug/android-build/' first."

and what the problem?
Also I enabled developer mode on my samsung device and enabled USB debugging

Comment: when I'm creating sample into Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/ directory it's works fine but it's not working into another directory.
error
Please run 'mingw32-make install INSTALL_ROOT=D:/Qt Samples/build-Sample_01-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_4_2-Debug/android-b‌​uild/' first.

Comment: QMake and spaces in paths don't mix well, try to build in a path without spaces (You have one in "Qt Samples")

Comment: I posted a bug report about this a while back: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13868 ... looks like it might be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

As Fran Osterfeld said, you can't have spaces in your build path.  I ran into that one a long time ago.

When I upgraded from Qt 5.4 to 5.5, however, I also ran into a problem with some other characters.  I had a build path like "..\Source\C++\MyProject...".  I had to remove the "++" and just name that directory "C".

Weird how this only popped up in the new Qt version!  I tried overriding the make path to use the prior version of mingw32-make (4.9.1 instead of 4.9.2) as that changed during the upgrade, but to no avail.  I'm not sure what the root cause is, but the point is try the most basic build path name you can as a starting point for fixing this issue.